# Rails Simple Calendar Gem Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am trying to get simple_calendar gem to work in my rails application. but keep getting an "undefined method `has_key?' for nil:NilClass"

Running Rails 5.0.0

Gemfile -> gem "simple_calendar", "~> 2.0"

Ran "bundle install" command, restarted application

Screenshot of error --> https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0K3J.jpg

Pastebin of controller and view page -> http://pastebin.com/8WX4dZNs

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copied files from  https://github.com/excid3/simple_calendar/tree/master/lib  directory into my applications lib directory

edited my calendar.html.erb file

```
<%= month_calendar do |date| %>
<%= date %>
<% end %>
```

Restarted server and got a calendar displaying

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation, the `calendar` helper takes a parameter which is a `Hash`. In your code snippet you've passed in a collection of events (`@events`), not a `Hash` of options.

If you want to pass the events in, the documentation shows how to do it.

```
<%= month_calendar events: @meetings do |date, meetings| %>
  <%= date %>

  <% meetings.each do |meeting| %>
    <div>
      <%= meeting.name %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Source: https://github.com/excid3/simple_calendar#rendering-events

So in your case, you'll want to pass your `@events` collection in as a key value pair like so: `<%= calendar events: @events do %>`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add the start_time alias definition inside the model you use for your events, here I have this inside my app/models/evento.rb

```
def start_time
  self.fecha
end
```

Here 'fecha' is the start date for my event. Then you have to manipulate your events as Carlos Ramirez explains, so you have to have something like this inside your 'calendar.html.erb':

```
<h3>Eventos (<%= @eventos.count %>)</h3>
<%= month_calendar events: @eventos do |date, eventos| %>
  <%= date.day %>
  <% eventos.each do |evento| %>
    <div>
      <%= link_to evento.title, evento %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

That should render the link to your event.